# NodeJS problem with cloning project axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, nodes, http-status-code-500

I am new in NodeJS I watched a tutorial from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1Kttu53qTg&list=LL&index=4&t=4969s

and its source code is from here

https://github.com/akashyap2013/CRUD_Application_Node

While I try follow every step that it said:

> In this project, we are going to create node CRUD application with express and mongodb.
>
> To Run this project Clone it and install modules using
>
> ```
> npm install
> ```
>
> Then Create config.env file and create PORT and MONGO_URI Variable and specify Value.
> That's it. You are ready to go. To execute this project just type
>
> ```
> npm start
> ```
>
> Enjoy...!

I encounter a problem which is

```
{"message":"Request failed with status code 500","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 500\n    at createError 
(C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NodeProject\\CRUD_Application_Node\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\createError.js:16:15)\n    
at settle (C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NodeProject\\CRUD_Application_Node\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\settle.js:17:12)\n    
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NodeProject\\CRUD_Application_Node\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\adapters\\http.js:244:11)\n    
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)\n    
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)","config":{"url":"http://localhost:3000/api/users","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.0"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1}}
```

Can anyone try cloning and see if you have the same problem as I am and how to solve it.
Thank you

Comment: Did you check the list of issues on the repository ( https://github.com/akashyap2013/CRUD_Application_Node/issues ) to see if someone already have the same problem ?

Comment: I have but non of the question is related to my problem